# Postgres query slow on production, fast on both staging and local

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I'm at a loss on this one. I have a fairly large query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE some_id IN (hundreds, perhaps even thousands of ids)
```

For some reason, while this query runs reasonably quickly for most of our users, we have one or two accounts for which is runs so slowly that we're hitting timeout errors (Heroku). I figured it must be related to those users' specific data, however, when I put a copy of the production database on our staging server, those same exact queries ran fast (< 2 seconds). I also tested the data on my local machine to the same effect: fast.

All three environments are running Postgres 11. I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Capture the execution plans in the three environments.

Comment: How you obtain "hundreds, perhaps even thousands of ids"   .. is a select /subquery?

Comment: @scaisEdge via a separate select query

Comment: explain better  .. show the code  .. please

Comment: *"Postgres query slow on production, fast on both staging and local"* the production database most likely have more data records then, staging and local can data sizes matter for query plans.. But we need to see the `EXPLAIN` of the queries and a table structure (`CREATE TABLE ...` statement)..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's the exact same data on all three, I took a snapshot of prod and put it on the other two

Comment: Oh now i see *" I figured it must be related to those users' specific data, however, when I put a copy of the production database on our staging server, those same exact queries ran fast (< 2 seconds)."* next time i should read the complete question before making a comment.. We still execution plans in all three environments and the `CREATE TABLE` statement..

Comment: *"All three environments are running Postgres 11. I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing this. "* Also the PostgreSQL config might be different on the three environments or differences in hardware performance mainly harddisk performance..

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay, I took a look at the query plan on prod vs dev--one difference I'm noticing is prod is doing a "merge join" that isn't happening on dev with the exact same query. I'm not used to reading query plans so there might be more I'm missing, but that seems fishy out the gate....

Comment: @StephenCorwin . . . You probably need to update table/database statistics on the production server:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html.

Comment: This fixed it! If you wanna post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @StephenCorwin, I am facing the same issue with my query (CTE & DateTime filter) at the prod server, taking a lot of time than the local & stage server. Could you please tell me how you found the issue & fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

If your  "hundreds, perhaps even thousands of ids"  is a result for a query  then you could avoid the in clause and use an inner join

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
INNER JOIN  (
  select id from my_table /* for hundreds, perhaps even thousands of ids */
) t on t.id = some_table.some_id
```

and be sure you have a proper index  on table   some_table  column some_id

Answer (score 0):

Very often joining to a `values` list is faster than an IN list:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM some_table st 
  JOIN ( 
     values (1), (2), (3), (4)
  ) t(id) on st.some_id = t.id;
```

Note the different format of the values list compared to the IN list. `IN (1,2,3)` becomes `values (1),(2),(3)`

Alternatively you can use a common table expression instead of a derived table

```
with id_list (id) as (
   values (1), (2), (3), (4)
) 
select st.*
from some_table st
  join id_list i on i.id = st.some_id;
```